# Custom View AddSubview programmatically, not shown UIElements…

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiview-hierarchy

I do this to add a Subview from Storyboard, which is a subview from a ViewController with its own Class. (TomStatusbarController) ...it is set as CustomClass in Storyboard. I do also Constraints with Layoutformats. This works fine, but the Statusbar is just red and i see no UIElements. I get lots on constraints warnings but it worked before, when i had it as an IBOutlet, but I have to change this now.

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
 [super viewDidLoad];   
    if (self) {
        self.tomCaptureStatus = [[TomStatusbarController alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 78)];
        self.tomCaptureStatus.layer.bounds  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 375, 78);
        self.tomCaptureStatus.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        self.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints  = YES;

        self.tomCaptureStatus.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];

        [self.view addSubview:self.tomCaptureStatus];
        [self.view superview];
    }
}
```

So why i don't see any thing, expect my backgroundcolor?

Tom

Comment: why did you add [self.view superview];

Comment: what do you want to achieve? A coloured background behind the status bar i.e. a view of screen width x 20 px?

Comment: Red color just for debugging. 
Superview for the Layoutformat. They need a superview to setup its constraints.

Comment: The TomnStatusbarController is part of a ViewController, which is embeded of a NavigationController… …is that a thing?

Comment: 3 remarks:

1. Never perform any UI-related tasks in viewDidLoad, because the UI elements are not properly laid out in viewDidLoad; Do it in viewDidLayoutSubviews instead.

 2. From you code, I can see that TomStatusbarController is a subclass of UIView, and for UIView's subclasses, TomStatusbarController is a very bad naming.

 3. The conditional statement if (self) is redundant.

Comment: thx! @hoang Cap